# Postgresql: pgadmin crashing every time when running long running query

Tags: postgresql

My pgadmin is crashing every time whenever i am running query which takes more time. my postgresql version is 9.5

Below is my ram detail

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        31G       228M       281M        56M        25G
Low:           31G        31G       228M
High:           0B         0B         0B
-/+ buffers/cache:       6.1G        25G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

I can see that swap memory is 0B. does this causing the postgresql to respond slow?? if yes then what i can do to improve the performance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "crash"? What is the error you get? Does pgAdmin really run on the server where Postgres is running? Are there any error messages in the [**server** log](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs)?

Comment: It's probably running out of memory because the query result set is huge.